# Magento 2.2.4 Product URLs show Category path even If Use Categories Path for Product URLs is turned off

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

In my Magento 2.2.4 setup some products of some categories show the category path and some do not. I checked all settings but I don't see the difference.
In all store views (Default, etc.) I have setup **NO** for the below setting: `Stores/Configuration/Catalog/Catalog/SearchEngineOptimisation/Use Categories Path` for Product URLs

Could someone help me?

Comment: The problem is that it does not happen with all the products and even in the same category some products yes and others do not.